# C++ trigger function when pointer unassigned/dealocated

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers, glfw

I am writing some code to wrap some GLFW objects.

I have a private `shared_ptr<GLFWwindow>` field on my class. GLFW has methods such as `glfwDestroyWindow`, which I use as `glfwDestroyWindow(_windowPtr.get())`, since the library is a C library.

I am curious if there is a way to call `glfwDestroyWindow` whenever the pointer is unassigned (specifically, just before it happens). Can this be done?

Comment: Yes, [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) allows you to specify a custom deleter function that is called when the pointer is to be destroyed.

Comment: Tactical note: prefer to ask how something can be done. "Can it be done?" can result in yes-or-no answers that are ultimately useless to you.